# powershell timer cannot stop immediately

Tags: powershell, timer

I am trying using powershell Timer to do some periodically job and once the job returns results that meet my expectation, I will stop running the job.

```
>$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
>$counter = 0
>$timer.Interval = 1000
>$timer.AutoReset = $true
>Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action { if ( $counter -eq 5 ) {$timer.Stop(); } ; $counter = $counter +1; write-host "counter is: " $counter; }
>$timer.Start()
```

The result is:

```
 counter is:  1
 counter is:  2
 counter is:  3
 counter is:  4
 counter is:  5
 counter is:  6
```

I was expecting the timer to stop once $counter reaches 5, but it continues to work. Is there any way to **immediately** stop the timer once some condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

Your IF should have an ELSE.  Your logic is not correct.  Try code like this:

```
$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$counter = 0
$timer.Interval = 1000
$timer.AutoReset = $true
$wait = $true
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action { if ( $counter -eq 5 ) {$timer.Stop(); write-host "counter stopped"; $global:wait=$false } else {$counter = $counter +1; write-host "counter is: " $counter; }}
$timer.Start()

while ($wait) { "sleeping..."; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 }
$timer.Close()
"exiting..."
```

**Output**

On my machine this displays:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
13     3a8d73a2-589...                 NotStarted    False                                 if ( $counter -eq 5 )...
sleeping...
sleeping...
counter is:  1
sleeping...
sleeping...
counter is:  2
sleeping...
sleeping...
counter is:  3
sleeping...
sleeping...
counter is:  4
sleeping...
sleeping...
counter is:  5
sleeping...
sleeping...
counter stopped
sleeping...
exiting...
```

Comment: $wait is always true. so "sleeping..." is always printed.

Comment: works for me, so not sure how else to help you here.  keep debugging your code i guess.  -kory

Comment: my version is 5.1

Comment: I figured it out. You need put "$timer.Stop();" at the end of IF.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for a bit late response
I think that this problem is simply caused by the order of instructions.
I think that the timer works completely fine and it truly stops immediately once the condition is satisfied.
The problem is that when counter reaches value of 5 the timer really stops but later this counter gets incremented to 6 and still gets printed out as 6

For the `-Action` parameter this instruction block was provided

```
{ 
    if($counter -eq 5) {
        $timer.Stop(); 
    } 
    $counter = $counter +1; 
    write-host "counter is: " $counter; 
}
```

I suggest replacing this instruction block by the following, first write counter then check it to stop the timer

```
{ 
    $counter = $counter +1; 
    write-host "counter is: " $counter; 
    if($counter -eq 5) {
        $timer.Stop(); 
    } 
}
```

So after typing it this way instead

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action { $counter = $counter +1; write-host "counter is: " $counter;   if($counter -eq 5) { $timer.Stop(); } }
```

the result becomes correct:

```
counter is:  1  
counter is:  2  
counter is:  3  
counter is:  4  
counter is:  5
```